# Inkscape - Why when I delete a node in Inkscape it becomes a straight line?

Tags: inkscape, vector

Long story short. Why when I delete a node in Inkscape it becomes a straight line?
It used to be automatically curved. I miss this function very much.

Comment: and it is still so...

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Unfortunately I can't replicate this problem. Deleting a node leaves a curve.

Comment: What becomes a straight line - from your formulation, the deleted node.

Answer (score 1):

I was about to post an image that explains my problem but just now I have checked and the problem has been fixed somehow. I just played with settings on the horizontal menu and in "Preferences". At first, nothing changed and I lost hope but when I checked now it works as expected. I must have tweaked some settings for the problem to appear. Anyway, I would like to know what was that for the future.

[image: Issue: Deleting a node makes straight line instead of automatic curve]

P.S. Thank you for responding, everyone. :)

Answer (score 0):

### Making an example[image: check it]

Maybe you should use this button [image: button]
Try and let me know

Comment: if this doesn't solve your "question" try to make an example with some images, we're glad to help you to catch this off ✨

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the preferences setting is Edit > Preferences > Tools > Node: Deleting nodes preserves shape.